# React js update child state from an event in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-d3

I have a WebSocket that's feeding data to the client and, i'm displaying it (data) in a chart using D3 in react, and so i want my chart to change according to the data, but to change the state of the chart component, i have to access it from the parent component where the onMessage event is defined, my problem is that the chart doesn't update :

Parent Component :

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }
  handleData(data) {
      let result = JSON.parse(data);
      this.setState((state) => {
        state.data.push(result.c.gas);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Websocket
          url={`ws://${window.location.host}/ws/mqtt_app/1/`}
          onMessage={this.handleData.bind(this)}
        />
        <Chart data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component :

```
const Chart = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);
  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // chart definition
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg ref={svgRef}>
        <g className="x-axis"></g>
        <g className="y-axis"></g>
      </svg>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the `setState` like this `this.setState((state, props) => ({
// code here
}))`

Comment: Try `this.setState(state => ({ data: [...state.data, result.c.gas] }))`

Comment: it worked !!! THANK YOU :D @Mario !!!

Comment: @user9909204 The reason is that you must modify the state by assigning a new value, in your case you were mutating its value. Would you mind if I make my comment in an answer and mark it correct?

Comment: @Mario yes please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a new value to the state variable. Please try this

```
this.setState(state => ({ data: [...state.data, result.c.gas] }))
```

In your case you were mutating its value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);
const svgRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // chart definition
}, [data]);
```

On first render of your `Chart` component you create local data with the data from parent component. With `useEffect` you're watching that local data (not data coming from parent), but it never changes because you never invoke `setData` inside of your `Chart` component. If it did work, local state wouldn't be possible.

Solution is to use directly the data from parent and put your `// chart definition` directly in the `Chart`, not in `useEffect`

```
const Chart = (props) => {
  const svgRef = useRef();
  // chart definition

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg ref={svgRef}>
        <g className="x-axis"></g>
        <g className="y-axis"></g>
      </svg>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Mario in the comments i've found the problem, first I removed the state from the child component, and used the props in useEffect, and after that as @Mario said i changed

```
     this.setState((state) => {
        state.gas.push(result.c.gas);
      });
```

with

```
this.setState((state) => ({ gas: [...state.gas, result.c.gas] }));
```

because, the state wasn't even changing, i only added an element to the gas array that i already had, but for the state to change a direct property should be resigned.